# RavenDB LuceneQuery Statistics method

Tags: lucene, ravendb

Is there any way to get query statistics for

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T> ()
```

like

```
session.Query<T>().Statistics(RavenQueryStatistics)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can just do this:

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>().Statistics(out stats)
```

Comment: what version of RavenDB? In my version (build: 373) there is no such method

Comment: Yeah it's in the latest builds, but I'm not sure which one it got added into. The latest build is #465 (http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/RavenDB) so #373 is pretty old!